# How to select multiple patterns for different roots using sql

Tags: java, sql

I'm working on java project to generate different patterns for different roots. I have two **tables** for my roots and patterns my program should generate root no `1` matched with pattern no `2,3,5...` and so on for other roots.
After some search I found sql instruction could help but I didn't understand it.

```
String SQL = "select ROOT.ROOTNAME , SUB.SUBNAME , SUB.SUBNO from NLP.ROOT , sub , subroot where  rootno=subrootno and subno=subno1";
```

Comment: Please show table structure and sample data.

Comment: You have to maintain mapping of your root and pattern in one table then execute query like: select pattern from table where root=1

Comment: @Tim There are three tables one for roots, one for patterns, and the third table combine the id of root with id of matched patterns but i couldn't generate that because i couldn't handle it with sql